# Proving an inequality between $\frac 1{n+1}$ and $\frac 1n$ and a definite integral

Tags: integration, inequality

For all natural numbers $n$, prove that $$\frac 1{n+1} < \int_n^{n+1} \frac 1t \, dt < \frac 1n$$

I have tried working with $\frac 1{t+1} < \frac 1t < \frac 1{t-1}$ but this doesn't help. The result I obtained was $$\log (\frac{k+2}{k+1}) < \int_n^{n+1} \frac 1t \, dt < \log (\frac k{k-1})$$

Answer (score 5):

For $t \in (n, n+1)$, $$\frac{1}{n +1} < \frac{1}{t} < \frac{1}{n}.$$
Integrate from $n$ to $n + 1$ to get the desired result. (well done improving your question)

Comment: Ohhhh! Recognizing that $n < t < n+1$ is what I needed! Then the integration of both the LHS and RHS is easy... Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 4):

If $n < t < n+1 \to \dfrac{1}{n+1} < \dfrac{1}{t} < \dfrac{1}{n} \to \dfrac{1}{n+1} = \displaystyle \int_{n}^{n+1}\dfrac{1}{n+1} dt < \displaystyle \int_{n}^{n+1} \dfrac{1}{t}dt<\displaystyle \int_{n}^{n+1}\dfrac{1}{n}dt=\dfrac{1}{n}$

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this graphically by drawing $y=\frac1x$ , and the appropriate rectangles as shown below.

[image]

ie. Area of AFDC < area under the curve < Area of EBDC